# Reading and printing sudoku input

Tags: optimization, c, io, windows, sudoku

I have seen programs to solve sudoku puzzles but to be honest.. They were badly written.
First of all, readability of the program itself was horrible and the code was really long and confusing.

So I decided to start from scratch, using my own style to write really good solver.
What I have this far is reading a board input from the user and outputting the board representation:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#include <iso646.h>
#include <conio.h>
#include <windows.h>

#define FOREGROUND_LBLUE 9
#define COLORSET_MAIN 3

char sudoku [9][9];

int chrton (unsigned char chr)
{
    if(chr >= '0' && chr <= '9')    { return chr - '0'; }
    else                            { return 0;         }
}

int main()
{
    char num = 0;
    char x = 0, y = 0;

    SetConsoleTextAttribute (GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_LBLUE | BACKGROUND_BLUE);
    printf("Validate numbers:\t\t\t\t\n\n");
    SetConsoleTextAttribute (GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), COLORSET_MAIN);

    // Part 1 : validating hint numbers
    while(y != 9)
    {
        if(kbhit() && isdigit(num = _getch()))
        {
            printf("%c"" ", num);

            sudoku[x][y] = chrton(num);

            if( ++x == 9 )                  { putchar('\n'); x = 0; y++; }
            if( not((x * x) % 3) and x)     { putchar('\t');             }
            if( not((y * y) % 3) and !x)    { putchar('\n');             }
        }
    }
    system("PAUSE");

    return 1;
}
```

Obviously it is written for Windows compatibility but I use it as for advantage to exploit some rules of commonly-accepted IO.

Comment: The code is not complete or functional for solving sudoku problems. Thus I believe that this question is off-topic. For the algorithm itself, sudoku is a [Constraint Satisfaction Problem (CSP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Constraint_satisfaction_problem) and you can use appropriate theory for finding a solution in a reasonable time.

Comment: I am pretty much aware it isn't complete. One of the reason why I posted it here. For a review and ideas for it to be completed appropriately.

Comment: This site is not about helping you write code. It's about improving the quality and performance of the code that you have already written and that is functioning correctly. Please see the [help center](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: And thats what I ask for.. improving the quality of the code.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it clear that you want input on what you have this far, and that this question is not about actually solving a sudoku puzzle.

Comment: Thanks. I am not a native speaker as it became clear already.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
char sudoku [9][9];
```

Please avoid [magic numbers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47882/what-is-a-magic-number-and-why-is-it-bad) in favor of constants.

```
#define TILE_WIDTH 3
#define TILE_HEIGHT 3
// a board is a square three tiles high and wide
// not defining a separate constant for that, as it is never used elsewhere
#define BOARD_WIDTH 3 * TILE_WIDTH
#define BOARD_HEIGHT 3 * TILE_HEIGHT
char sudoku[BOARD_WIDTH][BOARD_HEIGHT];
```

Then later

```
while(y != 9)
```

can become

```
while ( BOARD_HEIGHT > y )
```

Note that I also changed it from `!=` to `<`.  The `!=` is fragile in the face of future changes.  If you would increment `y` twice in one loop, you could shoot past your boundary condition.  This way your boundary condition is a region rather than a point, so it will trigger under more conditions.

```
        if( not((x * x) % 3) and x)     { putchar('\t');             }
        if( not((y * y) % 3) and !x)    { putchar('\n');             }
```

can become

```
        // tabs separate tiles horizontally
        if ( ( 0 == x % TILE_WIDTH ) && ( 0 < x ) )
        {
            putchar('\t');
        }
        // an extra blank line separates tiles vertically
        if ( ( 0 == y % TILE_HEIGHT ) && ( 0 == x ) )
        {
            putchar('\n');
        }
```

I'm not sure why you were squaring `x` and `y` there.  For a tile width of three, it doesn't matter.  The square of an integer is divisible by three if and only if the integer is divisible by three.  I'd avoid using logical operators with numbers that are not intended to represent booleans.

In C, it's the general style to favor the symbol versions of the logical operators over their word equivalents.

I reformatted your `if` statements there to match the enclosing `if` statement.  While internally consistent in the short case, your format there is distinctive enough relative to what most people do that I'd recommend against it.  It was also problematic here in that using the constants made the lines long enough to wrap in the text box.  And of course, the boundary as to when you use it is a bit fuzzy (you use it with all but one `if`).  I tend to prefer a consistent rule for all situations so that I can avoid defining boundaries like this.

I added comments here that explains why you might have been doing this extra output.  That's easier to read later and for others.  The reader can just check if that's what it is doing rather than try to figure out what it is doing and then why.  You could also spin these off into their own functions and let the names do the commenting, but given the length and number of variables used, it doesn't seem necessary.

```
char x = 0, y = 0;
```

This seems like an unnecessary optimization.  Yes, it saves a little memory, but it's such a tiny amount.  It's more readable to say

```
int x = 0, y = 0;
```

For the extra six bytes (assuming a four byte word), the readability improvement is worth it.  Particularly considering that the compiler often stores single characters in a word anyway, so it might not save you the six bytes.

```
char num = 0;
```

I don't like the name `num` here.  Your `chrton` function suggests that this can also be a space, so call it something else, say

```
int input = 0;
```

I also changed it from a `char` to an `int`, as that's what `_getch` returns.

```
    if(kbhit() && isdigit(num = _getch()))
```

Your 'chrton` function implies that it can get values other than a digit, but here you clamp down.  This seems wrong.

```
// Part 1 : validating hint numbers
```

Here you talk about validating hints, but you only read in solved boards.  You will probably need to loosen the `isdigit` requirement before proceeding.

This is also a bad use of a comment.  Given the length of the section, this suggests that most of the functionality should be in its own function

```
void validate_hint_numbers()
```

or

```
void fetch_valid_board()
```

That's self-commenting, making use of programmatic structure to separate into parts and names to indicate what it does.

```
int chrton (unsigned char chr)
```

I have no idea what that function does from the name.  It would help if you could find a more descriptive name for it, e.g. `sanitize_square_value`.

You're also doing a lot of implicit casts.  You convert the result of `_getch()` from an `int` to a `char` and then to an `unsigned char`.  Based on that, you return an `int` which is immediately converted to a char again.  I would think it would make more sense for `chrton` to take an `int chr` and return a `char`.

Comment: I do `isdigit` in order to not output anything if the input isn't digit.

Comment: Sure, but you said you're doing a solver.  So your input can be an incomplete board.  How are you marking squares that don't have a digit selected yet?  The normal way would be to mark them with a space.  As it is, you'd have to enter a `0` for them and you output a `0`, which is unintuitive.

Comment: I prefer to use a period `.` instead of a space because it makes it easier to count and to input.

Comment: @Brythan Yes, `0` is what I meant and choose for appropriate.
@Edward I could easily allow space or dot.. but `0` will be easier for the function to proceed later.

Answer (score 6):

I have found a couple of things that could help you improve your code.

### Avoid the use of global variables

I understand that it's just partial code so far, but it's generally better to explicitly pass variables your function will need rather than using the vague implicit linkage of a global variable as with `sudoku` in this code.

### Don't use `system("pause")`

There are two reasons not to use `system("cls")` or `system("pause")`.  The first is that it is not portable to other operating systems which you may or may not care about now.  The second is that it's a security hole, which you absolutely **must** care about.  Specifically, if some program is defined and named `cls` or `pause`, your program will execute that program instead of what you intend, and that other program could be anything.  First, isolate these into a seperate functions `cls()` and `pause()` and then modify your code to call those functions instead of `system`.  Then rewrite the contents of those functions to do what you want using C++. In this case, a better alternative would be `getchar()`.

### Be careful with `char` and `int`

Your `chrton` function returns an `int` and then stores it in a `char`-sized location.  Better would be to return `char`, since that's how `sudoku` is defined.

### Consider using `unsigned char` for subscripts

It's not technically wrong, but you may wish to use `unsigned char` for the type of `x` and `y`.  It eliminates a class of errors that can occur if the array subscript is a negative number.  This is a fairly minor point, however.

### Consider using more idiomatic C

While your use of `and` and `not` is not techncially wrong, because you have correctly included the `iso646.h` header, you should be aware that many experienced C programmers will be unfamiliar with these operator alternatives, and so if others read your code, it might be an impediment to their understanding of the code.  Similarly, your unusual formatting of `if` statements as one-liners is likely to seem a bit strange to experienced programmers.

### Consider separating input and output

Right now, the `main` function issues a prompt, reads in the sudoku board and then prints it out as each character is read.  A more modular (and likely more maintainable) approach would separate these into separate functions.

### Consider returning `0` instead of `1`

A non-zero return value is interpreted as an error condition on most operating systems.  Normal program exit should return `0` or `EXIT_SUCCESS` or simply omit it, because the compiler will automatically insert the equivalent of `return 0;` at the end of `main`.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> #define FOREGROUND_LBLUE 9
> ```

It's good that you are extracting magic numbers into macro definitions.
But when you do that,
it would be better to make the names be about the purpose of the constant,
not about its value. So I'd rename this to just `FOREGROUND`.

> ```
> SetConsoleTextAttribute (GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), FOREGROUND_LBLUE | BACKGROUND_BLUE);
> ```

I can't find the definition of `BACKGROUND_BLUE` in your post,
maybe you forgot or maybe it's defined somewhere else I don't see (I don't have Windows).
In any case,
instead of using `FOREGROUND_LBLUE | BACKGROUND_BLUE` here,
I would recommend to put this in another macro,
for example `CONSOLE_TEXT_ATTRIBUTES`.

---

> ```
> printf("Validate numbers:\t\t\t\t\n\n");
> ```

Are those `\t` characters really important? Won't they be invisible anyway in the UI?

---

> ```
> if(chr >= '0' && chr <= '9')    { return chr - '0'; }
> else                            { return 0;         }
> ```

The first `>=` condition can be changed to `>`,
as in that case the returned value will be 0 either way,
but without an extra subtraction step.

---

> ```
>         if( ++x == 9 )                  { putchar('\n'); x = 0; y++; }
>         if( not((x * x) % 3) and x)     { putchar('\t');             }
>         if( not((y * y) % 3) and !x)    { putchar('\n');             }
> ```

If I'm not mistaken,
the only time `!x` will be true is after it was reset to 0 in the first `if`.
As such, these conditions can be rearranged to eliminate some unnecessary evaluations.

Comment: `BACKGROUND_BLUE` is defined in `windows.h`. `\t` Are for label-style coloring the global event.